# Audio-Amplifier(5W)

Tags: amplifier, audio, analog

I'm working on an Audio Amplifier and I don't understand how the two resistors **R7** and **R5** can affect the gain of the circuit.

Gain = (1+R7/R5)

I would really appreciate if someone could give me an explanation why is this so.

Here's the circuit:

[image]

And beside this,what's the pupose of C3(220uF) on the T1 emmiter?

Comment: R7 and R5 are a feedback network similar to what you would see in an op-amp circuit.  The large cap provides an AC ground for the bottom of R5

Comment: You could treat this whole circuit as a black box (opamp). Where the T1 base is a noninverting input and T1 emitter is an inverting input. So we have a noninverting amplifier (opamp) with the gain  (as a first approximation). C3 is there to reduce the DC voltage gain to 1. Without it (without C3) any DC voltage at the Q1 base will be amplified by (1+R7/R6) and appears at the output But this is now what we want.

Comment: Guys, if you want to write answers, write them in the answer box below. Comments are for improving the question or asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an overview of your circuit so that we are on the same page, so to speak.

You have two quadrants of Sziklai output sections, upper and lower, for which the base voltages are separated by an adjustable VBE-multiplier to provide a fixed difference. (The Sziklais are missing a number of useful things, such degeneration resistors in the emitters of \$T_4\$ and \$T_5\$ or any current-limit circuitry.) \$C_8\$ bootstraps \$R_8\$ into a constant current sink (I often see this the other way so that the resistor is a source instead) with \$T_2\$ as the VAS, itself controlled by varying the \$T_1\$ collector current sourced through \$R_4\$.

---

Suppose you just completely removed \$C_3\$ and \$R_5\$ from the circuit. (By this, I mean "plucked them out" and not "shorted across them.") \$T_1\$ is still a CE amplifier stage with a quiescent current. That current still needs to flow through \$R_4\$, \$T_1\$'s collector, be combined with the base current, and get emitted out of \$T_1\$'s emitter to go ... where?? Well, it must be going through \$R_7\$ and to the output. In fact, if you built a working version of this circuit you actually *could* remove \$C_3\$ and \$R_5\$ (just leave the input open and unconnected to a source) and the circuit would find a quiescent point with the output close to the mid-point of the voltage rail's voltage.

Obviously, this only works if \$T_1\$'s base is biased correctly so that, after subtracting away the \$V_\text{BE}\$ voltage of \$T_1\$ and also subtracting away the voltage drop caused by the quiescent current passing through \$R_7\$, you get an output sitting midway. That's the requirement here. But that's not difficult to meet.

Now, the funny thing here is that the output is at end of the DC emitter leg. So if the signal at the base of \$T_1\$ lifts up on the base voltage (AC discussion now, but still without \$C_3\$ and \$R_5\$ is the circuit), it also lifts up \$T_1\$'s emitter by about the same amount. That means more emitter current, which means more collector current, which increases the voltage drop of \$R_4\$, which causes \$T_2\$'s collector to source more current (by a factor of 10X for each \$60\:\text{mV}\$ change in the drop across \$R_4\$) and to pull upward on its collector voltage. This lifts the base of \$T_4\$ and thus lifts the output voltage.

The effect here is that if you lift the base of \$T_1\$, lifting the emitter of \$T_1\$ and therefore one side of \$R_7\$, then the response is to lift the other end of \$R_7\$ up, too. And this counters (negative feedback) the initial impulse that lifted the base of \$T_1\$.

The effect isn't perfect, because there still must be just a very tiny increase in \$T_1\$'s emitter current (yielded by just a slight increase in the voltage drop across \$R_7\$.) This tiny increase is needed to provide a very tiny increase in the voltage drop across \$R_4\$ so that \$T_2\$ does in fact lift up the output in order to follow. So the output will ***almost*** but not completely follow the base input change at \$T_1\$. But it will be close.

So the DC gain is slightly less than 1. But almost 1.

That's true with or without \$C_3\$ and \$R_5\$ added to the circuit.

Or let me put this a different way. At DC, ***all*** of the output voltage is presented (less the voltage drop across \$R_7\$) to the emitter of \$T_1\$. Since the signal is presented to the base of \$T_1\$ and since the output ***follows*** the input and presents that signal right back to the emitter of \$T_1\$, all that really happens is .. very little. There is almost no change in the \$V_\text{BE}\$ of \$T_1\$. So almost no change in its collector current. Etc. The effect is that \$T_1\$'s base and emitter move up and down together with the signal, with the output following the input.

---

Now to your question.

At DC, \$C_3\$ has infinite impedance. So with or without \$R_5\$ present, at DC all that happens is... nothing much. \$C_3\$ just charges up to the voltage at the emitter of \$T_1\$ and sits there. And if you move the input at the base of \$T_1\$ around slowly enough (still DC from the circuit's point of view), then the gain is still going to be very close to just 1.

The important thing here is what happens when you add \$C_3\$ and \$R_5\$ back into the circuit and then, in effect, \$C_3\$ is treated as a dead short (if the input frequency is high enough to achieve it.) Now, you have a simple voltage divider that divides the output voltage and presents this divided result to the emitter of \$T_1\$. Now, \$T_1\$'s emitter "sees" only a fraction of the output. Not all of it.

Above, I wrote, "At DC, ***all*** of the output voltage is presented (less the voltage drop across \$R_7\$) to the emitter of \$T_1\$." That is no longer true. At AC, ***a fraction*** of the output voltage is presented (less the voltage drop across \$R_7\$) to the emitter of \$T_1\$.

That's the key to this.

Because the emitter only sees a fraction of the output change, \$T_1\$ continues to work still harder until its emitter is pulled up enough that it "seems to follow" the input. To achieve that, since only a fraction of the output change is seen by \$T_1\$'s emitter, \$T_1\$ must cause the output to move even more. In fact, by just enough more to counter the division caused by the new voltage divider. To counter the divider's \$\frac{R_5}{R_5+R_7}\$, the output must swing more by \$\frac{R_5+R_7}{R_5}\$. (Because when you multiply the divider ratio of \$\frac{R_5}{R_5+R_7}\$ by the gain of \$\frac{R_5+R_7}{R_5}\$, you get the net result of ***1*** that \$T_1\$ is struggling to achieve.

I hope that makes more sense?

Comment: I'm just confused on the part where you said:"T1 is struggling to achieve the net result of 1" what does it suppose to mean?

Comment: @SimonMaghiar Just look at things from T1's point of view. Only a fragment of the output change is presented to T1's emitter. But it's base still has the full signal change presented there. Suppose the signal rose 100 mV, and the output rose 100 mV so far, but the emitter sees only 10 mV of it. Then 90 mV remains as an added difference across the BE junction. But the collector current changes by a factor of 10X for only 60 mV difference. 90 mV means 32X!! So the output will be hard-driven for still more. It won't be exactly "1". But it will be VERY CLOSE to 1 before things balance.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help,now I get it, but let me put it another way.Because the signal on the emitter needs to follow the base voltage (emitter follower hence gain = 1) the T1 transistor is striving to achieve this. Because there's a voltage divider formed by R5/(R5+R7) tied to the emitter and output, T1 must counter this by amplifying the signal with the reverse of the voltage divider which is (R5+R7)/R5 **to maintain** the emitter gain at 1. I hope I explained it right..

Comment: @SimonMaghiar Quite nicely!! Yes. BJTs can be looked at from a number of perspectives. And seeing it here as an emitter follower with "gain=1" is a nicely compact way of summarizing it. Nice! I expect you have a good handle on things to have put it so well.

Answer (score 7):

The open-loop gain of the circuit is very high, determined by the configuration of transistors T1 and T2. (The rest of the transistors are either voltage followers or used for bias.)

Therefore, the closed-loop gain of the circuit is determined primarily by the feedback network, which is the voltage divider formed by R7 and R5. This feedback is applied to the emitter of T1, which makes it negative with respect to the primary signal input applied to the base. In other words, voltage at the emiiter serves to cancel out voltage applied to the base.

C3 blocks the DC path from the emitter of T1 to ground, forcing the DC current to flow through R7. This is required because with a single-ended power supply, the output node floats at approximately Vcc/2 (this is adjusted via R1), rather than at ground as it would with a bipolar supply.

Answer (score 2):

R5 is an emitter degeneration resistor, which reduces the gain of the transistor in exchange for better linearity and better control over the gain. Without R5, the gain would depend heavily on the \$\beta\$ of the transistor, but with R5, the gain of that stage approaches \$-\frac{R4}{R5}\$, and is more consistent across different transistors.

C3 is there to reduce the gain to 0 for DC bias, because the capacitor's impedance increases with decreasing frequency, approaching \$\infty\$ at 0 frequency.

R7 I am not so sure about. My best guess would be that it decreases the load on T1 by the output stage. It shouldn't decrease the unloaded voltage gain, but will decrease the power and current output from the stage.

Comment: Yes, but what about the gain of T2?

Comment: Thank for the explenation of C3,you are right! So the gain for DC bias is 0 because of the infinite impedance of the capacitor in DC.

Comment: @DaveTweed No one cares for the gain of T2 because the whole circuit has only 1 global feedback which is set by the two resistors mentioned.But it's true that T2 has the biggest amplification which will amplifie the AC singnal with a voltage ranging from +U and GND.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling there is a resistor missing in that schematic, from T1 emitter to ground, to set the DC working conditions for T1. Then R7, R5 and C3 form a completely conventional negative feedback path to define the gain the same way as a non-inverting opamp, 1+R7=R5, reducing to 1 at DC.

Comment: Not a missing resistor. Single-ended power supply requires the DC block.

Comment: @DaveTweed So R7 serves to set the DC conditions and T1 base is biased above Vs/2. (That would have been clear if there were some component values!)

Comment: Sorry I didn't put any components values on it,but I know for sure that the T1 base must be biased at Vs/2 (with the help of R1) allowing the AC signal to have a maximum trip from Vs/2 to Vs and from Vs/2 to 0 (GND)